# How do I run a check constantly in nodejs (discordjs) + How to send message to a seperate channel

Tags: node.js, discord

I want the bot to check a certain amount of time. so using date and time I have it going

```
 if (day == 4 && (hours == 15 && minutes >= 39) || (hours = 4 && minutes < 55)) {
//send message
    }
```

So that way it sends a message in a special channel

also - How do i send an embed in a specific channel

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the discord.js version you use, but I can give an example with v12.
In order to send a message to a channel, the bot must first be on that server.

to send a message;

```
client.channels.cache.get("channelid").send("message")
```

You can also look at embed usage here.
[Embed usage](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)